# Google Webapps: HTML tables render upside down on mobile

Tags: html, ios, ipad, mobile, google-apps-script

I am creating an equipment management and rental system for a student org that I participate in at my university. The webapp responds flawlessly on my computer, but there seems to be a bit of nonsense occurring when I try to run the webapp from my iPad or iPhone. (Evidently this also affects the desktop version of Safari in addition to the mobile version of Chrome.)

The webapp depends greatly on several, relatively simple HTML tables. When I run the webapp on mobile, the tables render in reverse, ascending order, rather than descending order like on the desktop version.

This (apparently) affects the integrity of the app, and I'm not exactly sure why.

The potential problem code:

```
function tableMaker(){
    var table = document.getElementById('AddT')

  //If the table is empty, start counting. Else, resume count from the last cell.
  if (table.rows.length < 1){
      var happy = "0"+table.rows.length
      var rownum = happy.slice(-2)
  }else{
      var happy = $('#AddT tr:last').prop("id")
      var happier = "0" + (Number(happy)+1)
      var rownum = happier.slice(-2)
  }

  var row = table.insertRow(table.length)
  row.id = rownum
  console.log("Creating cells with the ID: "+rownum)

  var cell0 = row.insertCell(0)
  var cell1 = row.insertCell(1);
  var cell2 = row.insertCell(2);

  //The first cell won't have the option to be deleted.
  if(table.rows.length > 1){
      cell0.innerHTML = "<text onclick='javacript:delRow(\""+rownum+"\")'>x</text>"
  }

  cell1.innerHTML = //Some painfully long select tag
  cell2.innerHTML = "<select id=select"+rownum+" disabled></select>"

  $('#addEquip').show("fade") //The div in which the table is contained
  $('#manLoad').hide() //A loading animation
}
```

[Two web browsers showing different results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/41vgr.png)
(Bortha Muggerums is my fictional co-developer. She's helped me through a lot.)

In this picture, one can see the problem that I am encountering. In Safari, each cell after the first is labeled "01" whereas in Chrome, each cell is labeled sequentially, as it is supposed to occur.

Ultimately I need this to be optimized for the iPad. Any and all help would be super appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Did you receive any kind of errors?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

```
var happier = "0" + (Number(happy)+1)
```

use

```
var happier = "0" + (parseInt(happy,10)+1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I've figured it out. For whatever reason, the desktop version of Google Chrome can equate`table.rows.length`to `table.length`while Safari and other web browsers require that mischievous `.rows`.

Changing

`var row = table.insertRow(table.length)`

to

`var row = table.insertRow(table.rows.length)` solved the issue.